# How do I set VSCode path so that it picks up my rufo extension for my Ruby on Rails project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, visual-studio-code, path

I’m using VS Code 1.65.0 on Mac Big Sur.  I have installed the rufo gem and the rufo-vscode extension (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=siliconsenthil.rufo-vscode).  After restarting VSCode, when I enter the shortcut (Cmd+Shift+I) to format a file, I get this error

```
rufo not available in path. Ensure rufo gem is installed
```

I’m not clear where VSCode is getting it’s path.  On my command line, I get this

```
$ which rufo
/Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2@myproject/bin/rufo
```

And this path is in my $PATH var, when I check my shell

```
$ echo $PATH
/Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2@myproject/bin:/Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2@global/bin:/Users/myuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.2/bin:/Users/myuser/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/opt/mysql-client/bin:/Users/myuser/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.1/bin:/Users/myuser/.opam/4.08.1/bin:/usr/local/opt/ansible@2.9/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

Where do I need to enter this info in VSCode so that it picks up ruff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open your `settings.json` in VSC and enter your `which rufo` output:

```
{
  ...
  "rufo.exe": "/Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2@myproject/bin/rufo",
  ...
}
```